# Reactive programming vs MVVM pattern for managing GUI updates

Tags: gui, mvvm, ui, reactive

Reactive programming and MVVM are two approaches that can address the problem of separating the domain layer from the UI.

- MVVM does this by defining a viewmodel, which is a data structure mapped to UI components. The UI display the data, and maybe update it when user occurs.
- a reactive framework defines a graph of observables which notify the UI that some piece of data has changed

Reactive frameworks are gaining mind share, both in mainstream platforms (with Rx in .net & java, react.js) and more experimental places (FRP in haskell).

I have mainly used MVVM with angular, and I find the simplicity to expressiveness ratio quite satisfying, although I have only worked on small/medium projects with it.

**What does a reactive framework buys the developer that mvvm don't?**

**Is there really a difference?** For example, knockout.js is advertised as a mvvm framework, but has a reactive feeling in its interface:

```
this.firstName = ko.observable("John");
this.lastName = ko.observable("Smith");

this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
```

Comment: MVVM is a **pattern** to separate the concern of presentation from domain. Reactive frameworks are **tools** that can be used to achieve this separation pattern. They aren't exclusive.

Comment: @AlexG Well, there are tools that coordinate the communication between a viewmodel & the UI. I would call those MVVM frameworks.

Comment: The point stands - KnockoutJS **uses a reactive framework** to enable the MVVM separation of concerns. AngularJS **uses dirty-checking** to enable MVVM. They are just different ways of achieving the pattern. Perhaps your question is *"What does the Reactive paradigm achieve in an MVVM framework that the Dirty-Checking technique doesn't?"*

Comment: @AlexG so you would say it is an implementation detail? I think it answers my question.

Comment: @Simon: I wouldn't qualify it as an implementation detail, but more as different approaches of communicating changes in the Model up to the ViewModel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are different non-competing concepts and they can easily work together to produce a great result.

In layman terms:

MVVM is useful to get away from the codebehind (GUI/model coupling) clutter.
Reactive approach is useful to reduce the event/callback clutter.

I would recommend learning a bit about XAML/WPF since Microsoft is the original inventor of the MVVM. Microsoft also produced a very good implementation of Reactive approach: Reactive Extensions.

Here is a decent attempt to combine them:

http://www.reactiveui.net
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI

Related SO question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763411/reactive-extensions-rx-mvvm